# Posting and Sharing photo with Facebook API but edit App name

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hi the web app i am working on posts photos in Facebook with the Facebook API. This works fine . But the image says "shared via #{App name}". I realise that the App name comes up since i have registered the app and using its app id for API usage. Is there any way to edit that App name and make is appear "shared via #{some new name}"